# This part of the rig doesn't stay the same scale

Tags: mesh, rigging, scale

The Part shown here is Not the Same Scale In Blender Then In Unity Here it is

Is Not the Same Scale as This
[image: See Here]

[image: See Here]

Is it Blender Or Unity If So any Fixes?

Comment: Did you apply scale on it before you exported it?

Comment: Yes and It even Didn't Work at All

Comment: If you export to FBX file try playing with "Apply Scaling" property in export dialog.